# Preferred way to set default values of nullable properties?

Tags: c#, properties

I'm in a dilemma. The (reduced) task is to redesign the following data holder class

```
class Stuff
{
  public String SomeInfo { get; set; }
}
```

to accommodate the demand that *null* mustn't be returned. I can think of two ways to achieve that and after deep consideration of 15 minutes, I simply can't decide which one is to be preferred.

Approach by constructor.

```
class Stuff
{
  public String SomeInfo { get; set; }
  public Stuff() { SomeInfo = String.Empty; }
}
```

Approach by property.

```
class Stuff
{
  private String _SomeInfo;
  public String SomeInfo 
  { 
    get { return _SomeInfo ?? String.Empty; }
    set { _SomeInfo = value; }
  }
}
```

Note that the creation of the *Stuff* instances might be done using the constructor as well as initialization, if that's of any significance. As far as I'm informed, there won't be any other restrictions (but you know how the customers' specifications not always reflect the reality).

Comment: Well - your first option doesn't meet your requirements - as I can still set the property to null. #2 is your only real choice.

Comment: If by initialization you mean some form of deserialization be aware that some implementations wont execute constructor code.

Comment: Another minor flavour on #2 might be to validate input when setting the value instead of when retrieving. If you find you're retrieving `null/Empty` values very often, instead doing the check once/rarely when setting might be preferred. EDIT: Note that this assumes you're vigilant enough not to set the backing field to null.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can only ensure that `null` is never returned when you use the property:

```
class Stuff
{
  private String _SomeInfo;
  public String SomeInfo 
  { 
    get { return _SomeInfo ?? String.Empty; }
    set { _SomeInfo = value; }
  }
}
```

The same approach is used by text-controls(e.g. in ASP.NET) where the `Text` property never returns `null` but `String.Empty`.

For example([ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)):

```
// System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
public virtual string Text
{
    get
    {
        string text = (string)this.ViewState["Text"];
        if (text != null)
        {
            return text;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
        this.ViewState["Text"] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Just to add another answer to this, you can also set a default value to a string object in a single statement;

```
class Stuff
{
  private String Something {get; set;} = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I doens't compile for me

Comment: It works only if parameter in model is not required and not sent. It doesn't work when parameter is sent in the body and value is null.

Answer (score 6):

You can also implement the logic in the setter rather than in the getter, that way your back field always has a valid value

```
class Stuff
{
  private String _SomeInfo = string.Empty;
  public String SomeInfo 
  { 
    get { return _SomeInfo; }
    set 
    { 
      if (value != null)
      {
        _SomeInfo = value; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to update the `if` check to set `String.Empty` instead of doing nothing. For example: `myStuff.SomeInfo = "Hello!"; myStuff.SomeInfo = null; Console.WriteLine(myStuff.SomeInfo); //prints Hello!` EDIT: Probably as simple as `_someInfo = value ?? String.Empty;`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I think this is really up to the OP. One could also decide to throw an exception in the case of an error...

Comment: +1 I agree that there are a few options. I only suggested it because assigning `String.Empty` would be consistent with the behaviour OP is demonstrating now.

Comment: @vc74 I think it's *null* just in the beginning, before any assignment, isn't it. Of course, I understand your point and I find it valid. However, I believe that it would still require a protector on both the setter and the getter. And since getter by itself suffice, the setter based protector is rendered redundant, isn't it? Haven't tried that in the code - I'm just figuring here.

Comment: @KonradViltersten it won't be null, it's initialized to empty

Comment: @vc74 In such case, I stand (contently) corrected. What is the mechanism that triggers the setter the first time? Implicitly from the constructor?

Comment: @KonradViltersten It's a field initializer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645756(v=vs.71).aspx The setter is not called on construction but the back field is initialized with a default value.

Comment: @vc74 I knew that properties are initialized to the default value **but** aren't you forgetting that *default(String)* is *null* and not *String.Empty*? The default value is then *null* for a property of class *String*, isn't it? Or am I missing an important detail here?

Comment: @KonradViltersten The property getter returns the _SomeInfo field value which is initialized to Empty, not null. This back field is guaranteed to never be assigned to a null value (at least in this part of the code) so the property getter will never return null. In other words, the SomeInfo property will never be null.

Comment: @vc74 I got unsure, since you seemed so certain, so I did the best thing one could. I tested it. Please see the code in my edit to your post. It appears that I was correct - the value is *null* from the start. I believe that you're missing the fact that *default(String) == null* holds and not *default(String) == String.Empty*. Please confirm so I can sleep in peace.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten of course it's null since you forgot the initializer private String _SomeInfo **= string.Empty;**